# After updated to the newest ADT, R.drawable noclassdeffounderror occurred

Tags: android

After updated to the newest ADT, R.drawable noclassdeffounderror occurred.
Before updating, everything is normal.

Comment: I know this seems obvious but, did you clean and rebuild everything?  If you did that did you try removing the project from your workspace and reimporting (assuming you're using eclipse)?  What have you tried? Updating to the latest tools, for me at least, usually takes a bit of finagling to get things in proper working order again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a library make sure the right R file is imported. I had this issue in the past after some tools update.

In my case application A was using library B. The drawable was in B and the import was R file from B project. Importing the R file from A project fixed it in my case.

Comment: how to do import R ?